# How to change x array in optimized function (scipy, Python)?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

Today I want to ask you next question - How to change x array in optimized function (scipy, Python)?

Example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize  

def function(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]<0:
            x[i]=0
    F = 0.0
    print list(x)
    for i in x:
        F += i**3
return F

n = 5
x0=[]
for i in range(n):
    x0.append(-1.0)
res = minimize(function, x0, method='Nelder-Mead')

print res
```

But result is array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]):

```
.........................  
.........................  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
  status: 1  
    nfev: 1006  
 success: False  
     fun: 0.0  
       x: array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])  
 message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'  
     nit: 148
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't change the array!** Instead, compute the result in some other way. For example, instead of the code in the post, write:

```
def f(x):
    return (x[x > 0] ** 3).sum()
```

and then:

```
>>> x0 = np.full((5,), -1)
>>> print(minimize(f, x0, method='Nelder-Mead'))
final_simplex: (array([[-1.      , -1.      , -1.      , -1.      , -1.      ],
                       [-1.000098, -1.      , -1.      , -1.      , -1.      ],
                       [-1.      , -1.000098, -1.      , -1.      , -1.      ],
                       [-1.      , -1.      , -1.000098, -1.      , -1.      ],
                       [-1.      , -1.      , -1.      , -1.000098, -1.      ],
                       [-1.      , -1.      , -1.      , -1.      , -1.000098]]),
                array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]))
           fun: 0.0
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 69
           nit: 10
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])
```

Here's a detailed explanation of how my function `f` works:

1. `x > 0` computes a Boolean array with the same shape as `x` that has `True` for each element in `x` that is greater than 0, and `False` otherwise. For example:

   ```
   >>> x = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
   >>> x > 0
   array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
   ```
2. `x[x > 0]` uses [Boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to select the elements of `x` that are greater than zero:

   ```
   >>> x[x > 0]
   array([1, 2, 3])
   ```
3. `x[x > 0] ** 3` is an array of cubes of elements of `x` that are greater than zero:

   ```
   >>> x[x > 0] ** 3
   array([ 1,  8, 27])
   ```
4. The `sum` method on an array adds up all the elements:

   ```
   >>> (x[x > 0] ** 3).sum()
   36
   ```